# How to prevent Vue.js overwriting prerendered HTML text content?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

My site uses Vue.js for certain components only (not for the entire site or page). The site itself is written in Python and rendered on the server side. One thing that's done on the server side, is parsing all the text content from HTML tags - the text content acts as a key, which would be translated into the key's value (e.g `<h1>^Default heading^</h1>` would become `<h1>Actual heading</h1>`). Since my Vue.js app is rendered on the client side into the app's container div, all text content of Vue app will be left untouched by the translator during SSR.

So the current solution is to define a JS object outside of Vue app, by 
adding in all the text content that Vue app uses (e.g {defaultHeading: ^Default heading^}. Vue app then uses that object's keys (which has gone through translation parser) for data binding. The problem with this solution is that it generates pointless extra code and makes maintaining code a bit harder (every time Vue app adds/removes a text element, it would also have to reflect in the JS object that was defined outside Vue app).

This lead me to test prerendering for my Vue app (SSR probably not, since the server is not using Node.js). Prerendering generated the app's HTML code and text elements were translated as wanted during SSR, but right after the Vue app itself was mounted, the translated text content was replaced by the values from Vue app - so `<h1>^Default heading^</h1>` that I got from prerendering became `<h1>Actual heading</h1>` and after mounting Vue app it went back to `<h1>^Default heading^</h1>`.

Is there a way to prevent certain text values to be overwritten by Vue app when using prerendered HTML? (Or maybe there's a better approach than prerendering for my goal?)

Comment: I'm having the same issue, I'll post something back if I find a solution, but by the looks seems like the app is ignoring the pre-rendered flag data-server-rendered="true" and removing it, almost like a router event happening I'll say.

Answer (score 1):

Did include this tag in the pre-rendered page just next to the id where you mount the app? (usually is id="app")

```
data-server-rendered="true"
```